# How to use Duplicator to migrate a WordPress site to AWS EC2 slice

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, migration

I’ve spent the past two days trying to get **duplicator** to deploy a site to a **AWS EC2** instance from another host. I have successfully used **Duplicator** for the past year to backup and restore various websites but I have had no joy on EC2.

**What I’ve done**
Setup EC2 LAMP stack:

- Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-1075-aws x86_64) PHP
- 7.0.33-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS ) mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for
- mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25
- domain, DNS etc. are all fine and point to correct location.

What I can’t get past is what **owner:group** should I set on the serving folder and what permissions should I set. I’ve even set the whole thing to **777** just to test and that didn’t work. When I use **www-data:www-data** I can get to the first stage of the migration process and after duplicator unpacks the archive I get hit with a **504 Gateway error**. Not one single tutorial or SOF post has helped and they often refer to out of date information. I can get it started with one set of permissions but the executing owner (php) changes the permissions on me.

Does any one how or of a working answer online?